# C++ - Count all possible scalene triangle with length of each side smaller than N

Tags: c++, c++14

With 3 <= N <= 100000, I tried the following O(n^2) algo but I want it to be efficient, O(n)
please help with homework :D

```
typedef long long ll;
int n;
int solve(int n)
{
    int ans=0;
    for(int i = n; i >= 3; i--)
    {
        int j = 1, k = i -1;
        while(j < k)
        {
            if(j + k > i)
            {
                ans += k - j;
                k--;
            }

            else
                j++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if O(n) is possible, but remember triangle sides have a special relation so not all numbers need to be considered

Comment: Hint: the number of scalene triangles with a) all sides having integral length and b) the longest side of length `k` is `(k-2)^2/4` when `k` is even, `(k-1)*(k-3)/4` when `k` is odd. Proof is left as an exercise for the reader (it's a simple sum of arithmetic progression). Now just add these up for `k` from 3 to `N` for an `O(N)` solution. I suspect there's a closed-form formula computable in `O(1)`, but am too lazy to try and derive it.